# Cual es la mejor manera para manejar imagenes en una aplicacion web

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express

Esta pregunta se divide en 2 partes: 
Contexto: Estoy haciendo un proyecto web con **express** js del lado del backend y **React** para el frontend dicho esto:

**1.-** 
Una vez que un usuario manda una imagen (sea de perfil o para cualquier otro uso) ¿Cuál es la mejor forma de guardar dicha imagen? Guardar la imagen en un archivo del proyecto y guardar la ruta en la base de datos (de ser así, como seria la ruta), guardar el archivo binario directamente en la base de datos?

**2.-** 
¿Cómo hago para para mandar la imagen que pertenece al usuario o producto de vuelta al frontend cuando se haga una petición que incluya la imagen? quiero evitar en la medida de lo posible utilizar librerías, esto para aprender a hacer las cosas de la manera mas "natural" posible, sin embargo si es muy complicado y extenso, no me cierro a usar alguna.

Comment: Esta pregunta está basada en opiniones, mi bro! Yo te recomiendo que uses un CDN, hay muchos y la mayoría tienen sdk's o apis para integrar bastante sencillo.

Comment: Le dare una revisada, no habia considerado esa opcion, alguno que recomiendes?